# How does typescript declare a negative type？

Tags: typescript

I know how to declare an excluded type in a function argument

```js
type ParameterExclusionString = <T>( arg: T extends string ? never : T ) => any

const test_fn: ParameterExclusionString = ( arg ) => { } ;


test_fn(123) // This is allowed

test_fn("abc") // This is wrong
```

But if this is not the case, the problem will be difficult to solve
For example, I want to construct a tool class that excludes certain types，Its name is called：ExclusionType

```js
type ExclusionType<T> = ? // How to write this tool？

const a1: ExclusionType<string> = 123 // This should be considered correct because 123 is not a string type

const a2: ExclusionType<string> = "abc" // This should be considered wrong
```

Comment: Currently, typescript is not supporting things like `type is not`  and you will have to either explicitly mention all the possible types or use the function. Does that address your question?

Comment: Someone might want to edit their answer to explicitly include the info that *negated types* as implemented (but never merged) in [ms/TS#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) are not part of the language so for the general case the closest you can get is some sort of generic helper function.

Answer (score 0):

This may be implemented with **argument type validation** concept

```
// pass type if ok, incompatible type otherwise.
// incompatible type may be 'error text string' for ovjects, and a ['error text tuple'] for strings.
type validate<def> = def extends string ? ['string can not be used as an argument'] : def

function test_fn<def>(value: validate<def>) {}

test_fn(123)
// ok

test_fn('123')
//      ~~~~~
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '["string can not be used as an argument"]'.
```

[plauground](https://tsplay.dev/WkaG2N)

or with type list exclusion:

```
type AllTypes = 
| null | undefined | boolean // constants
| string | number | symbol | bigint // sets 
| object | unknown[] // objects
| ((...a:any[]) => any) | (new (...a:any[]) => any) // functions

// won't work for less broad types, but well, that's impossible in TS atm
type ExclusionType<T> = Exclude<AllTypes, T>
const a1: ExclusionType<string> = 123 // This should be considered correct because 123 is not a string type
const a2: ExclusionType<string> = "abc" // This should be considered wrong
```

Comment: `const a3: ExclusionType<string> = () => {};` and dozens of other things would be considered correct. Just out of curiosity: How would a bullet proof union of literally every type except `string` look like?

Comment: @Behemoth easier to say fow it *won't* look like, and that's `{} | Record<never, never> | any | unknown`

Answer (score 0):

I think all you really need is a simple conditional type that checks for a string in your generic.

```
type NotString<T> = T extends string ? never : T;

const test_fn = <T>(arg: NotString<T>) => {};

test_fn(42);
test_fn("test");
//       ~~~~ -> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to 
//               parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
```